# setting the progressbar values for-loop a burning tools

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

I am implementing a CD/DVD burning tool by using IMAPI (Image Mastering API by Microsoft). I need to put a **ProgressBar** into the main screen to indicate user about the progress of writting process.
I am using **Microsoft Visual FoxPRo 9.0 SP 2** for my development.
Can anyone can tell me how can I **collect the statistics to set the values** of the Progress Bar...??

Please Help

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think you have bigger problems if you're using FoxPro for this.

Answer (score 1):

This is really an IMAPI question surely?

This [similar query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782730/imapi2-in-vb-2008-progress-bar) would seem to indicate that you need to handle IDiscMasterProgressEvents progress events from IMAPI, and possibly on a separate thread. So I'm not sure how feasible that would be with Visual FoxPro.

You might find it easier to do this in .NET and then leverage that from the VFP side.